# Extending and retracting sprites along curve - Objective C / cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocos2d-iphone

Hey guys I'm pretty new to programming in general, I have searched and learnt as much as I can but I have no idea how to go about doing this

Essentially its like a rope that extends in the direction of a touch, but the starting location can change (and likely will). The rope itself is an array of sprites (unless thats a bad idea?). So far I can draw the line etc, and I have a clue about moving the start location but I do not know how I would:
Move the starting location without moving the entire line of sprites
Moving the line of sprites in such a way to follow a curve
Retract the line of sprites, although I imagine it would be the reverse process for moving it forward and so not too difficult if I can understand how to do the first part.

So far I know about bezier curves, vrope and have googled every search term I could think of but still dont quite know what to do.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.